# How to Make a colored Notification Icon for my App

Tags: xamarin.forms

i got a PNG image and i want to make it my notification icon that appears on receiving any notifications i dont want it to be grey and white and idea how to achieve that ?

FB and youtube notifications icons are colored

My code

```
 notificationBuilder.SetContentTitle("My-App")
                    .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.My_PNG_ICON)
                    .SetContentText(messageBody)
                    .SetAutoCancel(true)
                    .SetShowWhen(false)
                    .SetContentIntent(pendingIntent);
```

i used this link with my PNG image but it gives out a white and grey icons [Link](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-notification.html#source.type=image&source.space.trim=1&source.space.pad=-0.05&name=NQ3)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44810283/how-to-use-different-notification-icon-in-android-for-the-notification-area-and

Answer (score 0):

On the `notificationBuilder` call chain, there should be a method called `SetColor`. Use that when trying to set notification title/icon color.

```
notificationBuilder.SetContentTitle("My-App")
                   .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.My_PNG_ICON)
                   .SetContentText(messageBody)
                   .SetAutoCancel(true)
                   .SetShowWhen(false)
                   .SetContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                   .SetColor(new Color().ToArgb()); // NEW LINE TO SET COLOR
```

You may need this line as well, but test to make sure

`.SetColorized(true)`

Answer (score 0):

`notificationBuilder.SetSmallIcon` can not show the real color, you can custom a **[RemoteViews](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews)** to use it for `notificationBuilder`. Then can show what your wants.

The sample code as follow:

```
RemoteViews contentViews = new RemoteViews(PackageName, Resource.Layout.custom_notification);
contentViews.SetImageViewResource(Resource.Id.icon, Resource.Drawable.heart_save);
contentViews.SetTextViewText(Resource.Id.tv_left, "Custom title");
contentViews.SetTextViewText(Resource.Id.tv_right, "Custom content");

NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);
Notification notification = notificationBuilder.SetOngoing(true)
        .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.check)
        .SetContentTitle("App is running in background")
        .SetPriority(1)
        .SetContent(contentViews) // here add custom RemoteViews 
        .SetCategory(Notification.CategoryService)
        .Build();
        
StartForeground(Constants.SERVICE_RUNNING_NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
```

`custom_notification.xml` in **layout** folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingStart="48dp"
    android:paddingEnd="48dp">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_lock_idle_alarm" />
    
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_left"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="Left" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_right"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="Right" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

The effect:

[image]

Comment: thx for your time and help, but that is not what i wanted, the notification icon appears white on the top bar , i want it to look colorized same as facebook or youtube icon bars

Comment: @XAMMOT2 Okey, do you have a try with testing on a physical device? In my tested device, it always shows the colorized icon.